# Changes of Internal Energy un open system

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

My professor says the internal energy of a system can be calculated as $U=n T c_v$. Now I always thought that we could only calculate a change in internal energy $\Delta U = n c_v \Delta T$.

Following this idea, he says that a recipient that contains gas and loses a certain number of moles at constant temperautre undergoes a change in internal energy of $\Delta U = T c_v \Delta n$.

I've never seen any of this in any book. I believe he is assuming that the internal energy at 0 Kelvin is zero, which I believe is not true. However, in the case of the recipient losing gas,I wouldn't know how to calculate $\Delta U$.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you assign an reference state for internal energy such that the internal energy per mole u of the gas is zero at $T=T_r$.  This reference state is going to be held fixed for the material both entering or leaving the open system, as well as the material within the system at any time.  Then, in the initial state of a constant-temperature system, $U_{init}=n_{init}C_v(T-T_r)$ and, in the final state, $U_{final}=n_{final}C_v(T-T_r)$.  So, $$\Delta U=\Delta nC_v(T-T_r)$$Typically, in the overall energy balance on the system, including entering and exiting streams, $T_r$ will cancel out (just as it would for a closed system).

Please note, however, that if chemical reactions are occurring, the equation for   the internal energy and the specification of the reference state has to be extended to take this into account (using the concept of "internal energy of formation").

Comment: I understand, but if there is only a exit, no entrance of gas in the recipient, still $\Delta U$ depends on $T_r$, which we don't know, so we can't calculate $\Delta U$.

Comment: No.  Not if you include the exit stream in the balance.  You have been learning about the version of the 1st law applicable to open systems, correct?  That version of the first law includes the enthalpy of the exit stream.

Comment: Yes I know the balance for an open system. Anyways I would have to calculate the point enthalpy of the leaving stream, there is no entering stream to get a $\Delta h$ term

Comment: That's not a problem.  You just use the amount that has left times its h.  Doesn't your textbook cover situations like that?  The amount entering does not have to match the amount leaving, except at steady state.

Comment: I can't find it on my book nor the internet. Could you explain me?

Comment: Neglecting kinetic and potential energy effects, $$\frac{dU}{dt}=\dot{Q}-\dot{W}_s+\dot{m}_{in}h_{in}-\dot{m}_{out}h_{out}$$where $\dot{W}_s$ is the rate of doing shaft work.  I'm sure you've seen this in some form before.

Comment: Here is one of many links:  http://www.learnengineering.org/2013/03/frist-law-of-thermodynamics-open-system.html

Comment: Yes I know the balance for an open system, but I don't know how to apply it in the specific case I mentioned above in which a gas exits the recipent. No entrances, only a gas exiting at constant temperature. That would leave:
$$\frac{dU}{dt} = \dot Q - \dot m_{out} h_{out}$$.
But then how do you calculate $h_{out}$?

Comment: The value of $h{out}$ depends on what is being done.   If the tank is adiabatic, Q dot is zero, and, if  the gas exits through a valve, the value of $h{out}$ is the same as h in the tank (no enthalpy change across the valve) at the moment that the differential mass is leaving.  If the tank is somehow held isothermal, Q dot is not zero, but u and h in the tank don't change, and $h{out}$ is equal to the (constant) h in the tank throughout the change.

Comment: Sorry I truly do not understand where you are going. My question is simple, is it correct to calculate te internal energy as $U = n c_v T$? I mean the value of the Internal Energy in a particular state.

Comment: I would not calculate it that way.  I would always use a reference temperature state for the zero in U.  Furthermore, this equation would be quite inappropriate if the heat capacity were temperature dependent, such that $U(T)=\int_{T_r}^T{C_v(T')dT'}$.  I've already pointed out that using a reference temperature for U will not pose any problems in applying the 1st law because it will cancel out.  Sorry, but I don't have any ideas on how to express it any better.

Comment: Well I totally agree with you! I also believe that considering that $U$ is zero at 0 Kelvin is wrong, that we can only calculate a change in $U$ when temperature changes. But my professor uses it all the time! For example, when he calculates the $\Delta U$ of a recipent that loses gas at contstant temperature: $\Delta U = T c_v \Delta n$.

Comment: What can I say.  In some cases, such as for an ideal gas with constant heat capacity, he can get away with doing this.  But it is a bad way to teach people this stuff, and will become a problem for them in other cases when it will actually be incorrect.  I would never teach it this way.  I totally agree with you too.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer! This is actually the second time I do a course in thermodynamics. Unbelievably, the one I'm doing now is far worse than the previous one. Sorry for the misunderstanding. How would you go about calculating the $\Delta U$ in the case I stated before, in which a recipent loses $\Delta n$ moles of gas at constant $T$?

Comment: I gave that in my original answer for the case of constant Cv and constant temperature.  If the Cv were not constant but the temperature were, then $\Delta U=\Delta n\int_{T_r}^T{C_v(T')dT'}$.  If the temperature were also changing, then $\Delta U=n_fu(T_f)-n_iu(T_i)$, where $u(T)=\int_{T_r}^T{C_v(T')dT'}$.

Comment: I see, Thanks Chester! You're awesome! Sorry for insisting, I think this professor will give me a hard time during this course. Thanks a lot and hope you have a great day!

Comment: It would be preferable instead of discussing the answer in the comments section, to include improving statements into it and clear the comment section accordingly. This is beneficial for later visitors.